# Regular expression from a Language

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression for the following language.

L = {w ε{a,b}^* | w does not have any instances of abb}

Below is my regular expression, which doesn't take care of abb

((a|b)*(aaa|aab|aba))|(ε|a|b)

How do I fix it so that there are in instances of abb. Also, the * is the exponent, just for your information

Valid Inputs: aabab, abababaa

Invalid Inputs: abb, abbab

Comment: Can you provide a list of valid and invalid inputs?

Comment: alright updated it

Comment: So it's just any combination of `a` and `b`, as long as it contains at least one instance of `aaa`, `aab`, or `aba`, and doesn't contain `abb`?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: Give this a try: `^(?!.*abb)(?=.*aaa|aab|aba)[ab]+`

Comment: it doesn't work for aba, if I just type that

Comment: Works fine for me here: https://regex101.com/r/iDnU15/1 What language/tool are you using for this?

Comment: oh I was using g, is there a way to do this without using question mark or no?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with G. Actually I'm not even sure which language you're referring to (there are 4 listed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G_programming_language). It might not have support for regex lookahead, which would make this problem very complicated to solve.

Comment: well would urs work with python?

Comment: Yes, python has a robust regex module.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of regular expressions, involving math, logic, and general computer science. I suggest applying some additional relevant tags to your question so that people who know about such things might see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is pretty simple:

```
\b(?:(?!abb)[ab])+\b
```

- any string that is made of combinations of a|b
- that does not contain abb

[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bkPsNd/1)